# How to Find two or more words matching from given String using Pattern Matcher class in java?

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I used below code for the matching of two words from the given string, but it's not working.

```
String inputText = "I want to know relating to cloud based erp services.";
Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
words.add("erp");
words.add("cloud");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("erp|cloud");

Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
if (m.find())
{
    return m.group();
    System.out.println("Yes we providing it.");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for `"(?i)erp.*cloud|cloud.*erp"`, see [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/xDhenD).

Comment: @dhruv_0707 - I don't understand your question now. Could you explain what is the issue?. Your code now prints "Yes..."

Comment: @ TheLostMind Suppose we find both or either cloud and erp  words match from the given my string than I want to return statement like "Yes we are provided it."

Comment: "both or either" - that means `"erp|cloud"` does exactly that. If *both* should be present, use `erp.*cloud|cloud.*erp` or `^(?=.*cloud)(?=.*erp)`. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/nxSVYF).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew thanks it's working.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew How to do same thing dynamically ?

Comment: Isn't that dynamic enough?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew We have multiple questions like :
1. "I want to know your company working on Cloud based ERP Services?"
2.1. "Want to know Cloud based ERP services Price Tags?"
3.1. "I want to know Cloud based ERP products developed by your company?"
And all of those above mentioned questions the answers is fixed.
So, in that situation what should we do if we go through database(Dynamically terms) otherwise prefer other way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: I do not get what your problem is. You have a hashset of terms, right? Then use my solution, and if you have a trouble, come back and let know.

Comment: See an updated non-regex approach. I will revert the regex one if you confirm you need to check for context.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew  thanks it's working.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since now you have reached 15 rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just check if your input contains all the strings from the hash set using a simple check: use `.filter(s -> inputText.contains(s))` and then check if the filtered set size is equal to the hashset size. If yes, all the terms are present in the string:

```
String inputText = "I want to know relating to cloud based erp services.";
Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
words.add("erp");
words.add("cloud");

if (words.stream().filter(s -> inputText.contains(s)).count() == words.size()) {
    System.out.println("Yes we providing it.");
} else {
    System.out.println("No, we are not providing it.");
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/n4G8z6).

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code as :

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("erp|cloud");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
    String match = "";
    if (m.find())
    {
        match =  m.group();
        System.out.println("Yes we providing it.");
    }
    return match;
```